# create 2d array from 1d arrays of non-equidistant points?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, matlab, interpolation

I have been trying to create 2d array/image from three 1d arrays. The arrays are latitude, longitude and temperature. For each value of lat and lon I have temperature. But the lat-lons are not equidistant. I tried delaunay triangulation in MATLAB, but the surface is only showing in the plot. I want to export it to 2d array so that I can do further analysis. Is there any way?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to understand how the temperature behaves in between your measurement stations. If you are willing to use linear or cubic interpolation, then the function `griddata` should do the job for you.

Note that this function would interpolate, but not extrapolate. Points lying outside the hull of your original points would come up as NaN. You should deal with those separately.

```
% Number of data points and grid points
N = 10;
Ng = 1000;
% Three arrays
x = rand(N, 1);
y = rand(N, 1);
t = rand(N, 1);

% Create a rectangular grid
l = linspace(0, 1, Ng);
[X, Y] = meshgrid(l, l);

% Interpolate the data
% WARNING: Points outside the convex hull of the original points
%   would show up as NaNs!!!
T = griddata(x,y,t,X(:),Y(:),'cubic');
T = reshape(T, size(X,1), size(X,2));

% Plot the surface
surf(X, Y, T, 'EdgeColor', 'None');
T(isnan(T)) = 0; % This would mess up the surface, though
```

Here is a link for more information (may expire):
http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/visualize/representing-a-matrix-as-a-surface.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The temperature behaves like a circular pool of water. In the middle it is colder than the edges. Kind of like a radial function. I used griddata as [x,y]=meshgrid(lon,lat);
z=griddata(lon,lat,sst,x,y);
figure
surf(x,y,z); but array z makes sense when plottaed as a surface alongside x and y.

Comment: You can just columnize all arrays as:
`x=x(:); y=y(:); z=z(:); data=[x, y, z];`